# change database connection during runtime

Tags: c#, db2, odbc

**Given**

I have the follow situation: During the runtime of my application I must be able to switch the database connection from an ODBC connection to a DB2 Connection and and conversely.

**Problem**

All my methods work fine. If i establish a connection to ODBC it works. If I establish a connection to Db2 it works fine. But if I try to connect to Db2 and afterwards to the ODBC driver I get an error that tells me he could not find the right database.

**Example:**

If I try this:

```
public void HelpMeTest() {
        string odbcConnectionString = string.Format("DSN={0};UID={1};PWD={2};", "MY-DNS", "myUser", "pwd");
        string db2ConnectionString = "Database=myDataBase;";

        OdbcConnection odbcCon = new OdbcConnection(odbcConnectionString);
        odbcCon.Open();
        odbcCon.Close();

        DB2Connection db2Con = new DB2Connection(db2ConnectionString);
        db2Con.Open();
        db2Con.Close();

    }
```

It works fine. But it I try this:

```
public void HelpMeTest() {
        string odbcConnectionString = string.Format("DSN={0};UID={1};PWD={2};", "MY-DNS", "myUser", "pwd");
        string db2ConnectionString = "Database=myDataBase;";

        DB2Connection db2Con = new DB2Connection(db2ConnectionString);
        db2Con.Open();
        db2Con.Close();

        OdbcConnection odbcCon = new OdbcConnection(odbcConnectionString);
        odbcCon.Open();
        odbcCon.Close();
    }
```

I get an error during odbcCon.Open(); which tells me that my database is in the wrong format, because he thinks that MY-DNS is the name of the database and not a DSN.

```
ERROR [HY501] [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1001N  "MY-DNS" is not a valid database name.  SQLSTATE=2E000
```

Some ideas?

Comment: Try checking what the `odbcCon.Driver` property contains in each case. I suspect that in the second example OdbcConnection delegates to the IBM CLI driver that is already loaded at that point.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "using" statements, do you get the same "blocking".

```
public void HelpMeTest() {
        string odbcConnectionString = string.Format("DSN={0};UID={1};PWD={2};", "MY-DNS", "myUser", "pwd");
        string db2ConnectionString = "Database=myDataBase;";

        using (DB2Connection db2Con = new DB2Connection(db2ConnectionString))
        {
            db2Con.Open();
            db2Con.Close();
        }

        using (OdbcConnection odbcCon = new OdbcConnection(odbcConnectionString))
        {
            odbcCon.Open();
            odbcCon.Close();
        }
    }
```